# When using useDispatch() inside useEffect(), action doesn't appear to be called immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to dispatch an action when a page is first mounted. This action set `loading` to be true immediately, then set it to false after 2 seconds.

Noticing that it has different behaviours when I use hooks/react component. When I write it in a react component using `componentDidMount`, everything works fine. But with hooks `useEffect`, there's a 0.3 second time gap before the load action is called. What leads to this tiny time gap? Shouldn't `useEffect` be equivalent to `componentDidMount`?

**Running Example**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-satoshi-qut8i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**useEffect()**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { load } from "./actions/user";

const Router = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(load(true));
  }, [dispatch]);
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.user.loading);
  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>Loaded</div>;
};

export default Router;
```

**componentDidMount()**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { load } from "./actions/user";

class Router extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.load(true);
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>Loaded</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    loading: state.user.loading
  }),
  { load }
)(Router);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `useEffect` and `componentDidMount` run in different portions of the React lifecycle.

`componentDidMount` and `useLayoutEffect` run synchronously, at the end of the "commit phase".

`useEffect` runs asynchronously with a brief delay, separate from the "commit phase".

So no, they are not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know the difference before. Does that mean some feature (such as not displaying this brief delay) can only be implemented by class component but not by react hooks?

Comment: No, `useLayoutEffect` is the most exact equivalent to `componentDidMount/DidUpdate`, as they both run synchronously in the commit phase.

Answer (score 0):

because `useEffect` runs after react render its component